# Given an ergodic property that guarantees convergence of sample means to an expectation, how can I bound the Cesàro Mean of expectation of terms?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I have a sequence of (not iid) random variables $\{E_{i}\}$ that converge in distribution (actually, in total variation) as well as in $\mathcal{L}^{2}$ to $E_{\infty}$. For all nonnegative functions $f$ with $\mathbb{E}[f(E_{\infty})]<\infty$, it's established that
\begin{align}
\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}f(E_{n}) \overset{\mathrm{a.s.}}{=}\mathbb{E}[f(E_{\infty})].
\end{align} I would like to bound (again for a nonnegative $f$)
\begin{align}
\underset{T\rightarrow\infty}{\lim\sup}\text{ }\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\mathbb{E}[f(E_{n})].
\end{align}
In my particular case, I've been unable to uniformly bound the random variables $f(E_{i})$, so I cannot use, for example, the reverse Fatou's Lemma to interchange the limit and expectation to show something like $\underset{T\rightarrow\infty}{\lim\sup}\text{ }\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}f(E_{n})] \le \mathbb{E}[\underset{T\rightarrow\infty}{\lim\sup}\text{ }\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}f(E_{n})]$. Does anyone have any advice for how I could try to proceed-- in particular ideas for how to interchange the limit and expectation without some kind of uniform bound?

The thing is that I don't much about the function $f$. I do know some potentially relevant facts. I can prove that $\mathbb{E}[f(E_{n})]$ is always finite.

Comment: Fatou's lemma does give a (lower) bound on the $\liminf$ of the expectation, which is also a lower bound on the $\limsup$.

Comment: You cannot get any upper bound.  Take $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ independent and uniform over $[\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{2}{2^n}]$. Take $Y$ independent of $\{X_n\}$  and geometric with success probability $1/4$.  Define $E_n=X_n1\{Y_n>n\}$. Now $0\leq E_n\leq 1$ for all $n$ and $E_n\rightarrow 0$ almost surely and in $L^2$ (also, $E_n=0$ for all suitably large $n$).  Define the nonnegative function $f(x)=1/x$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$. So then $f(E_n)=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$. However,  I believe I have rigged the problem so that $E[f(E_n)]$ is finite but goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comments, the best possible upper and lower bounds are:
$$ E[f(E_{\infty})] \leq \limsup_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^TE[f(E_n)] \leq \infty$$

---

**Lower bound:** Suppose $f$ is a nonnegative function such that
$$ \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=}^T f(E_n) = E[f(E_{\infty})] \quad \mbox{almost surely}$$
We have
\begin{align}
\limsup_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^TE[f(E_n)] &\geq \liminf_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^TE[f(E_n)]\\
&\overset{(a)}{\geq} E\left[\liminf_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^Tf(E_n) \right]\\
&= E[f(E_{\infty})]
\end{align}
where (a) holds by Fatou's lemma for sequences of nonnegative random variables.  The lower bound is achievable by defining $X_n=X_{\infty}=0$ for all $n$.

---

**Upper bound:**
Define $Y$ geometric with success probability $1/4$.  Define
$$E_n=(1-\frac{1}{2^n})1\{Y>n\} \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Then we surely have $0\leq E_n\leq 1$ for all $n \in \{1, 2,3, \ldots\}$, and we surely have $E_n=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$. It follows that $E_n\rightarrow 0$ surely (and in $L_2$). Also, for any real-valued function $g$ we surely have $g(E_n)=g(0)$ for all sufficiently large $n$, and so $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^T g(E_n)\rightarrow g(0)$ surely.

Now define the continuous and nonnegative function $f:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ f(x) = -1 + \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Since $f(0)=0$ we surely have $f(E_n)=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$. However
\begin{align}
E[f(E_n)] &= E\left[f\left((1-\frac{1}{2^n})1\{Y>n\}\right)\right] \\
&= E\left[f\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)|Y>n\right](3/4)^n + E[f(0)|Y\leq n]P[Y\leq n] \\
&= (3/4)^nf(1-\frac{1}{2^n})\\
&= (3/4)^n\left(-1 + 2^n\right)
\end{align}
and so $E[f(E_n)]$ is finite for all $n$, but $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^T E[f(E_n)]\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Cool counterexample for the upper bound! I think maybe I'll be able to uniformly bound the expectations $E[f(E_{n})]<B$. The Cesearo mean then lets me upper bound the "time average of expectations" by $B$. Do you think this is the best possible upper bound with that additional stipulation?

Comment: Yes, that would then be the best upper bound: For any $b>0$ you can redefine $E_n=x_n1\{Y>n\}$ where $x_n$ is chosen so that $(3/4)^nf(x_n)=b$ for all $n$, (which means $x_n = \frac{b}{b+(3/4)^n}$ and so maintains $0\leq x_n<1$ for all $n$), so then $E[f(E_n)]=b$ for all $n$.